# JButton will not be unpressed

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

Im developing a text editor where I have a sidepanel and menu bar for formatting text, example you can make text Bold by going through the menu or pressing the button. But, when pressing the button it stays pressed even if i press it again. If i do it through the menu bar it presses and then depresses when choosing Bold again. So, through the menu bar it works, when doing it in the side panel it does not work.

Code for pressing and depressing the button, this is in my side panel (JPanel)

```
    public void press(JButton button){
    System.out.println("Pressed: " + button.getModel().isPressed());
    if(button.getModel().isPressed()){
        System.out.println("1");
        button.getModel().setPressed(false);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("2");
        button.getModel().setPressed(true);
        System.out.println("Pressed2: " + button.getModel().isPressed());
    }
}
```

In my render view class I have this action listner

```
private public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String action = e.getActionCommand();

    if(action.equals("New")){
         newTA();
    }else if(action.equals("Bold") || action.equals("B")){
        contr.bold();
        sidePanel.press(sidePanel.bold);
    }
}
```

Where "Bold" goes through menu and, "B" through the sidebar.
Both menu and sidepanel toggles the bold formatting, just that the button in sidepanel will not be depressed when pressing it again.

Anyone have had a similar problem and might have a solution?

Comment: There is no need for you to be playing with the ButtonModel directly. Normally you just click the button and the text is changed by the attributes but the state of the button remains unpressed, since the attributes will not apply to the entire text. See [Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for a working example. However, if you are trying to keep the button pressed on a click then you should be using a `JToggleButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [JToggleButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) and you will not have to worry for pressed/unpressed state.

Answer (score 0):

I used JToggleButton as suggested, it worked fine!
in my press()-function i set and unset it manually so its accessible through the menu bar aswell.

```
public void press(JToggleButton button){
    if(button.getModel().isSelected()){
        button.getModel().setSelected(false);
    }
    else{
        button.getModel().setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

and in my render class

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String action = e.getActionCommand();

    if(action.equals("Bold")){
        contr.bold();
        sidePanel.press(sidePanel.bold);
    }
```

Last code is executed when bold is pressed from menu bar
and under here, executed when pressed in side panel

```
 else if (action.equals("B")){
        contr.bold();
    }
```

Apprish!